# How to add timestamps for todo items in agenda view?

Tags: org-mode

This is my first post here. I'm quite new to emacs and currently using doom emacs with some my own configs. I'm trying to customize my own agenda view these days, and what I want is to add timestamps(schedule or deadline) to each todo item in the agenda view.

Currently, I use `agenda-and-all-todos` and it looks like this:
[image]

I've found something like this (the '1 d. ago' and 'in 2 d.')
[image]

where I wish to add the same column of my scheduled tasks or tasks with deadlines while keeping showing the ordinary todos without timestamps. How should I achieve this?

PS: I've tried `org-agenda-columns` and it turns out to be ugly, see

[image]

Thus, I'm looking for a better solution here.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the question is: I think it would help if you had a (small) example Org mode file with entries similar to what you want and show how you current agenda view shows it and how it falls short of your expectations. In particular, I don't know what the relationship between your various images is (note also that posting images is frowned upon in this forum: Org mode is a textual format so you can cut-and-paste text and use Markdown to show it verbatim).

Comment: What @NickD said. Please specify what you want to do clearly. Thx.

Comment: One can insert time stamps into Org agenda view only in follow mode. I recommend that you set up your agenda in your agenda files, rather than in agenda view. Otherwise, create custom agenda templates with timestamps.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @NickD , all I want is something like this in todo list or agenda view: 
```
Tasks:    TODO [#A] some tasks SCHEDULED: <2021-01-04>
```
Actually all I want is the `SCHEDULED: <2021-01-04>` part in the todo lists.